# Шрифт Symbol и браузер Vivaldi

Tags: css, шрифты

Есть html, сконвертированный из MS Word и там используется шрифт Symbol. Почему-то этот шрифт не работает в Vivaldi. Например, такой код:

```
<font style="font-family:symbol">¥</font>
```

должен вывести символ бесконечности ∞, но выводится символ ¥. В Chrome и Firefox всё так, как нужно.

Вот этот шрифт: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x2x91djnj2lgik3/symbol2.ttf

Как сделать так, чтобы отображались правильные символы?

Comment: Зачем выводить пустой квадрат?
[скрин](http://prntscr.com/dccplw)

Comment: @A.Gusev вы открыли приведённый мной html в Vivaldi и у вас отобразился пустой квадрат? Или что?

Comment: Нет, я скрин приложил. Сижу через хром.
Т.е. если у вас отображается по другому, то м.б. дело не в вивальди.

Comment: @A.Gusev извините, забыл включить javascript на сайте скриншотов. На самом деле это символ бесконечности &#xF0A5 Возможно, у вас нет шрифта для этого символа.

Comment: @A.Gusev я ошибся, этот символ из области для частного использования и его как раз и добавляет шрифт Symbol. Изменил вопрос.